# Does execution of build/release pipeline create a new base folder with the path containing agent number or build/release number?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

1. Does each build pipeline execution create a new base folder under which all code is downloaded, artifacts created?
2. Does each release pipeline execution create a new base folder under which all artifacts are downloaded?
3. In build pipeline example below, what is the `1` in the path below? Is it the build number or is it the agent number?
4. In release pipeline example below, what is the `r1` in the path below? Is it the release number or is it the agent number?

Build pipeline - 
Build.SourcesDirectory/System.DefaultWorkingDirectory/Build.Repository.LocalPath: The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example: c:\agent_work\1\s

Release pipeline - System.ArtifactsDirectory/System.DefaultWorkingDirectory/Agent.ReleaseDirectory: The directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a release. Example: C:\agent_work\r1\a

Answer (score 0):

**Does each build pipeline execution create a new base folder under which all code is downloaded, artifacts created?**

With self-hosted agents, no. The first run of a build will create a folder for that build pipeline at `{DRIVE_LETTER}:\{PATH_TO}\{BUILD_AGENT_WORK_DIR}\{BUILD_NUMBER}` (on Windows). This folder will be re-used for subsequent pipeline builds. In Azure DevOps Services agents, it may wind up being the case that you never build twice on the same agent/host, so the folders will be created each build. See the docs for System.DefaultWorkingDirectory at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

**Does each release pipeline execution create a new base folder under which all artifacts are downloaded?**

No. The base folder is created on the first run and recycled  for subsequent runs, similarly to the way builds create folders. These will be found at `{DRIVE_LETTER}:\{PATH_TO}\{DEPLOYMENT_AGENT_WORK_DIR}\r{RELEASE_NUMBER}`.

**In build pipeline example below, what is the 1 in the path below? Is it the build number or is it the agent number?**

Build number.

**In release pipeline example below, what is the r1 in the path below? Is it the release number or is it the agent number?**

Release number.

NOTE: The re-use of the folders during the build/release depends on the job being processed by the same agent. In Azure Devops Services (as opposed to Azure DevOps Server), this may never happen depending how short-lived agent hosts are. There may or may not be any affinity between your pipelines and build agents.

Comment: Does every build and release create new folders?

Comment: @variable, yes. Say you have a build and a release for some app. Folder `1` will be created on the machine hosting the build agent(s) the first time the build runs on each machine hosting an agent. Folder `r1` will be created on the machines hosting the deployment agent(s) the first time the release runs.

Comment: What about the 2nd time. Will the same folder be reused or new will be created?

Comment: @variable, no, on the 2nd time the folder(s) will be re-used.

Comment: Wont it create a new build number and release number folders for every subsequent build and release respectively?

Comment: @variable. No, it will not create new build number or release number folders on the 2nd, 3rd, or Nth build or release.. If you have any self-hosted agents, I'd recommend exploring the `_work` dir (_work is the default, and it could have been named something different). Please let me know if there's something that's unclear.

Comment: @variable, if you're not self-hosting build agents, your build jobs may never be processed by the same agent more than once, so in that case, the folders will be recreated each time on the new agent.

Comment: On self hosted agent I am noticing that build pipeline reuses same folder. And 1 in that case is the agent number. Where as release pipeline creates new folder for each relese. Like r1, r2, .... bit confused with this

Comment: @variable, you're mistaken. The 1 is not the agent number. From the docs: "Agent.BuildDirectory - The local path on the agent where all folders for a given build pipeline are created. For example: c:\agent_work\1" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=yaml#agent-variables

Comment: @variable, a single release pipeline does not create new folders (r1, r2, etc)  each time a release is triggered. From the docs "Agent.ReleaseDirectory - The directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a release. The directory is cleared before every deployment if it requires artifacts to be downloaded to the agent. Same as System.ArtifactsDirectory and System.DefaultWorkingDirectory. 
Example: C:\agent\_work\r1\a" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#release-variables

Comment: In your second last comment, 1 is build number. So for next build of the same pipeline, wont it be 2? And in your last comment, r1 is release number. So for the next release of the same pipeline, wont it be r2?